# php function imap_open failing when run through command line on windows with script

Tags: php, command, imap-open

I am running Windows Server 2012, and is also running apache and PHP on an intranet.

When I pull the script through http://localhost/script.php it runs without issue and no problems.

When I run the same script through the command line with the prompt:
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\php.exe C:\wamp\www\script.php

it dies at the line when it gets to imap_open.

Here is the full code:

```
$hostname = '{email-host:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());
```

Any ideas on why it will not work through command prompt.

in php.ini, I have included:

```
extension=php_imap.dll

extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: the php.ini for the command line is different then the one for apache, usually its  cli.ini, so likely you don't have the extension enabled in that one...    What error do you get when it `dies`, that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. There are two php.ini files, in for wamp, you have to go to the folder: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3 and edit the php.ini in that folder and that controls the settings for the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the extension in the `cli.ini` or `php-cli.ini` file.  Which is a separate config then the one Apache uses.

That's my guess at least...  Without knowing what error you get when it dies.